# RestKit map XML element body

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

How do I create a RestKit object mapping for an XML element body to an object attribute?

XML:

```
<response>ok</response>
```

Mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Response class]];
[responseMapping mapKeyPath:@"???" toAttribute:@"body"];
```

Comment: If you have an attribute 'response' in your Response Object, like this :
[responseMapping mapKeyPath:@"response" toAttribute:@"response"];
Can you detail Response object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want the string 'ok' in Response.body (who is an attribute of Response object) :

```
[responseMapping mapKeyPath:@"response" toAttribute:@"body"];
```

It works ?

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. Problem was I was mapping the object to its own element keypath. The `response` element is actually wrapped in a `result` element:

`<result><response>fail</response></result>`

so I changed my original mapping: 

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:responseMapping forKeyPath:@"result.response"];`

to:

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:responseMapping forKeyPath:@"result"];`