# How to map XML textContent with RestKit?

Tags: ios, xml, cocoa-touch, restkit

I have a XML like this:

```
<rss>
<channel>
 <item>
  <title>something</title>
  <description>...</description>
  <category>cooking</category>
  <category>housing</category>
 </item>

 <item>
  ...
 </item>
 ...
</channel>
</rss>
```

It's a RSS Feed, with an array of items inside a channel, containing many tag/properties (title, content,...), with a collection of category tags.

I can parse it with RestKit for the channel/item/title/content part with this:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *itemMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Item class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
[itemMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
[itemMapping mapKeyPath:@"description" toAttribute:@"content"];

RKManagedObjectMapping *channelMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Channel class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
[channelMapping mapKeyPath:@"item" toRelationship:@"items" withMapping:itemMapping];

[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:channelMapping forKeyPath:@"rss.channel"];
```

But I'm at lost for mapping categories... I've tried something like that:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
[itemMapping mapKeyPath:@"category" toRelationship:@"categories" withMapping:CategoryMapping]
```

But somehow the text content inside the  tag is not mapped to my propertie 'name' inside the Category class. For sure I didn't use this 'name' in the code here, because I don't know where to put it.

How can I parse text-only XML tag with RestKit? Is there something like:

```
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@".text" toAttribute:@"name"];
```

?

(doesn't work as is)

Comment: this is close [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9196947/1040553)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try:

> [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"" toAttribute:@"name"];

I'm not sure if it will work though.

Comment: @Paul.. You are my hero for today.. :)

Comment: How about the equivalent for ReskKit 0.2?